# Express application has one API(route) which takes full date of birth and returns the age but instead its returning an empty object

Tags: node.js, express

I got a route /age which takes date of birth in format yyyy-mm-dd and 
return the age of the person as output

```
 app.get('/age', (req, res) => {

    getAge = (dob) => { 

     this.dob = req.query.dob;
     var today = new Date();
     var birthDate = new Date(dob);
     var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
     var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
     if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
          age--;
        }
     return age;

    }

    res.status(200).json({age: getAge})

});
```

But somehow I'm ending up in getting an empty string.

if input is `/age?dob=1994-03-10` then the respond should be

`{"age":24}`

Comment: If you want to respond to an http get request with parameters (?dob=1993-03-10) I think you need to use this: `app.get('/age/:dob, (req, res etc etc` Then access the parameters in your function from the req.params object (req.params.dob).

Answer (score 0):

Given that `getAge` is actually a correct function you need to *CALL* the function.

```
res.status(200).json({age: getAge()})
```

You should isolate the function from the route, it means that everytime someone hits the `age` route a function is created. 
Also, if you are taking `dob` as parameter then you don't need to get the dob from the params.

```
const getAge = (dob) => {
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dob);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
    return age;
}

app.get('/age', (req, res) => {
    const dob = req.query.dob;
    res.status(200).json({age: getAge(dob)})
});
```

**EDIT**: As you said in the comments the function needs to be inside the route, so this will work as well.

```
app.get('/age', (req, res) => {
    const dob = req.query.dob;
    const getAge = (dob) => {
        var today = new Date();
        var birthDate = new Date(dob);
        var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
        var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
        if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
            age--;
        }
        return age;
    }
    res.status(200).json({age: getAge(dob)})
});
```

Ideally utility functions like this needs to go to your own `utils.js`(or whatever the name of your util module is) so that other modules can use it.

**EDIT 2:** From your other questions(including the deleted one) it is clear that your basic problem is not understanding how Javascript works as a whole. You are using Node.js and Express but you lack the basic building blocks. I suggest you read some JS/Node.JS tutorials. One of my favorite JS resource [js.info](http://javascript.info) give it a whirl if you like. Also read up about async operations including promises. It will help you immensely on the long run.

Comment: for some reason I've to use it within the route only cannot use it separately as a controller function `app.get('/age', (req, res) => {    });// end calculate age`

Comment: Then it is bad practice, ideally utility functions like this needs to go to your `utils.js` so that other modules can u se it. But if you cannot then just make it inside your route and use it.